# Sprint Wireless Toolkit

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit, java-wireless-toolkit

At the risk of being told not to ask where I can find a particular program, I'm asking where I can find a particular program. I need to develop an app in LWUIT (yes, old technology, I am well aware). Does anyone know where I can find a copy of the Sprint Wireless Toolkit 3.3.2?

[Sprint's website](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/technologies/java_me/p_java_me.jsp) certainly doesn't have it anymore. I searched and searched, so I'm asking that if anyone has an old copy somewhere if they can throw it in a Dropbox link or something for me to get it. I'm reading the book *LWUIT 1.1 for Java ME Developers* and the book relies heavily on using that toolkit.

Comment: Someone down-voted my question. I'm shocked (not). Congratulations, Mr. Downvoter, on helping perpetuate the Stack Overflow reputation of being an unpleasant place for honest dialogue.

Answer (score 0):

Sprint Wireless Toolkit is just an emulator. I can't believe any book relies heavily on a specific emulator.

Nowadays the package to download is Java ME SDK 3.4 from here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/javame/javame-sdk/downloads/index.html

(Stick to v3.4. Do not download v8.x as those are for Xlet development and doesn't contain MIDP APIs).

I have to admit though that I don't have any experience with Java ME SDK 3.4 because it was only made available for Windows, and I'm using Linux. So I'm still using the old Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 from Oracle, and/or other emulators.